# Google places api not returning postal code for some places

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have a form which would collect location information from the user. I'm using Google places api to autocomplete the location information. It works great. Everything got filled out nicely however there are some places (e.g. my workplace which is a building), Google does not return a postal code for it.

I followed this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) from Google address autocomplete. It also doesn't return postal code for my workplace. So I'm not entire sure what I did wrong.

Below is my code:

**HTML**

```
    <div id="location-autocomplete" style="display: none;">
        <div class="half-formfield">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Address)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Address, new { @class = "two-third-field", id = "street_number", required = "required" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.UnitNumber, new { value = "Unit Number" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UnitNumber, new { @class = "one-third-field" })
        </div>
        <div class="half-formfield">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.City)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.City, new { @class = "half-field", required = "required", id = "locality" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProvinceOrState)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ProvinceOrState, new { @class = "half-field", required = "required", id = "administrative_area_level_1" })
        </div>
        <div class="half-formfield">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ZipOrPostalCode)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ZipOrPostalCode, new { @class = "half-field", required = "required", id = "postal_code" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Country)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Country, new { @class = "half-field", required = "required", id = "country" })
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Clear Address" onclick="clearAddress()" id="clear-btn" class="service-form-btn"/>
```

**JS**

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
    // to geographical location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        { types: ['geocode'] });
    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
    // populate the address fields in the form.
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        fillInAddress();
        showAddressComponent();
        setTimeout(hideAddressSearch, 800);
    });

}

function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        if (component != "route") {
            document.getElementById(component).value = '';
            document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }
    }
    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            console.log(val);
            if (addressType != "route") document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
            else if (addressType == "route") document.getElementById("street_number").value = document.getElementById("street_number").value + " " + val;
        }
    }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
                position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,
                geolocation));
        });
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

I wonder if this is a bug or simply Google doesn't know the postal code of the building. In that case, is there simply any work around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google's own example doesn't find a zip code for that address. So this is not related to the wall of boilerplate code you pasted. This sounds like a question to address to Google.

Answer (score 0):

There is a postal code for this address, but only a part (I guess it's called FSA-code).

The function didn't recognize this part, because for this address the returned types-array is:

```
 ["postal_code_prefix", "postal_code"]
```

...but the function only checks the first item of the types-array.

possible fix:

```
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressTypes = place.address_components[i].types,addressType,val;
    for(var j=0;j<addressTypes.length;++j){

      addressType=addressTypes[j];

      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        break;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: It's still not working. What FSA code did you get from it? V7X?

Comment: That's actually not the correct FSA code for the building. Google maps also gives out simply just that code if you look up the address on Google maps.

Comment: As least for me this building seems to be Bentall Tower 1, and at their [**website**](http://www.bentallcentre.com/contact-us) I see a postal code `V7X 1M9` . When the first 3 characters of a canadian postal code are the FSA it seems to be correct.

Comment: There are multiple Bental Towers around the complex. The one that has V7X is the main tower I assume. Our building postal code starts with V6E.

Comment: Any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will explore more ideas.**

```
  function initDefaultAutoCompleteFunction() {

        var objAddress = document.getElementsByClassName('autocomplete-address');
        $(objAddress).each(function (index, address) {
            if (typeof (address) != 'undefined' && address != null) {
    
                let options = {
                    types: ['address'],
                    Fields: ['address_component', 'formatted_address'],
                    componentRestrictions: { country: ['us', 'ca'] }
                };
    
                let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address, options);
                autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
                    debugger;
                    let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                    if (place) {
                        let zipOrPostalCode = null; // or set empty etc.                    
                        $.each(place.address_components, function (index, value) {
                            let addressType = value.types[0];
    
                            if (addressType == 'street_number') {
                                // value.short_name; //this is your street number
    
                            }
    
                            if (addressType == 'route') {
                                // value.short_name; //this is your route                         
    
                            }
    
                            if (addressType == 'postal_code' || addressType == "postal_code_prefix") {
                                // value.short_name; //this is your postal_code    
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var location = place.geometry.location;
var lat = location.lat();
var lng = location.lng();


var latlng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
            geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                            if (results[0]) {

                            for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                                var types = results[0].address_components[i].types;

                                for (var typeIdx = 0; typeIdx < types.length; typeIdx++) {
                                    if (types[typeIdx] == 'postal_code') {
                                        //console.log(results[0].address_components[i].long_name);

                                        var pincode = results[0].address_components[i].short_name;
                                        alert('pin'+pincode);

                                    }
                                }
                            }   

                            $('#pac-input2').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                            infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                            //infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        }

            });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers with nothing else are discouraged.